# Data Migration to RDS?

Tags: database, oracle, amazon-web-services, migration, rhel

I'm trying to use `impdp` on `RHEL` without GUI. I'm not sure if my direction is correct. Since `RHEL` has no GUI, so what I do is install `SQLcl` from https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqlcl-downloads.html

Basically my objective is to migrate on-premise oracle database to `RDS` and this `RDS` can only be accessed by particular `EC2` instance. In other words, I would need to find a way to perform Data Migration by SSH into this `EC2`. Wondering if anyone can shed some light on whether my direction is correct? Or is there any simpler way to do it?

Comment: Do you want to migrate from a premise Oracle database to Amazon RDS? Or migrate to an EC2 instance with Oracle instance?

Comment: @DmitryDemin: I want to migrate from a premise Oracle DB to Amazon RDS

Answer (score 0):

[Importing Data into Oracle on Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html)

You do not have direct access to the RDS instance file system.

There are several data migration solutions.

The first solution using S3 Bucket.

1. Export data from the premise database using expdp.
2. Upload the dump file to the S3 cloud.
3. Copy Dump File from Amazon S3 Bucket to the RDS instance.
4. Use DBMS_DATAPUMP to Import the DUMP File on the RDS Instance.

The second solution using Database Link.

1. Export data from the premise database using expdp.
2. Create a Database Link to the RDS Instance.
3. Use DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER to Copy the Dump File to the RDS Instance.
4. Use DBMS_DATAPUMP to Import the DUMP to the RDS Instance.

The third solution using Oracle XE, if you cannot make a db link between your DB and RDS instance.

1. Export data from the premise database using expdp.
2. Create a free instance of EC2(1 CPU core, 1G RAM, 30GD HDD ) or a
   paid instance with a large disk and CPU.
3. Install a free database version of the Oracle XE version on EC2 instance.
4. Copy files to the DUMP directory to Oracle XE on EC2 instance  via the sftp protocol.
5. Create a Database Link to the RDS Instance Use DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER to
   Copy the Dump File to the RDS Instance.
6. Use DBMS_DATAPUMP to Import the DUMP to the RDS Instance.

And other solutions without using DATA PUMP:

- Importing Using Oracle SQL Developer.
- Oracle Original Export/Original Import Utilities
- Oracle SQL*Loader Oracle Materialized Views using db link

Comment: Another option is to use AWS DMS.